# Vue: sharing methods in a js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm working on a multipage website in vue and often need the same methods for different views.
I read that you can do that with a shared .js file and it works if i have my "test method" downloadModel as a single function but as soon as i try to split it up, i get a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined ().
How can i fix this? Sry i'm relatively new in this world. :)

```
export default {
methods:{  
    downloadModel(id) {
        this.printMessage('Download',id)
    },

    printMessage(string,id){
        console.log(string, id)
    },
```

}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

In you share.js file :

```
function downloadModel(id) {
    this.printMessage('Download',id)
}

function printMessage(string,id) {
    console.log(string, id)
}

export { downloadModel, printMessage };
```

In your page.js file (for exemple)

```
import { downloadModel, printMessage } from 'js/shared.js';
```

Note that you don't need to export / import printMessage if this function is only call by downloadModel and you don't need to use it by yourself in page.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html?redirect=true) to achieve what you want here. If several components use the same function, you can put that in a mixin and that mixin in as many components as you like.

Example:

###### Mixin

```
// mixins/shared.vue
export default {
    methods: {
        sharedFunction() {
            console.log("Hi, i'm a shared function!");
        }
    }
}
```

###### Component 1

```
// components/comp1.vue
import SharedFunctionMixin from '../mixins/shared.vue';

export default {
    mixins: [SharedFunctionMixin],
    
    mounted() {
        this.sharedFunction();
    }
}
```

###### Component 2

```
// components/comp2.vue
import SharedFunctionMixin from '../mixins/shared.vue';

export default {
    mixins: [SharedFunctionMixin],
    
    mounted() {
        this.sharedFunction();
    }
}
```